# Animate DOM After Element Removal

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a structure that looks something like this:

```
<div>
  <img>
  <img>
  <img>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to removes the image elements with a nice little animation. This is part is working fine. However, when the animation is complete, the rest of the elements jump to fill the left space. I would like to animate this motion similar to the way [jQuery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) does when the page is resized, but it seems rather wasteful to include the entire plugin just for this. Is there another way?

[See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HP7fb/1/)

Comment: I think that your css has to change in some way that will differentiate one image from the other. Something about top I think. Something that will change when a div is caused to move up and animate that change. I'm not good with css though.